# No funciona el evento de registro porque el evento de inicio de sesión esta primero pero al cambiar de orden comienza a dar fallos por el hoisting

Tags: javascript, funciones, dom, function, funcion

En este código se intentó hacer que funcionara un login de usuario, pues al principio de la prueba no funcionaba el evento de registro porque el evento de inicio de sesión estaba primero.

Luego se cambió el orden, a ver si le lograba hacer algo con el hoisting (llegué a pensar que era por eso), pero nada pues al estar en registro.html no encuentra el id inicioSesion,  y es por eso que considero que no completa el evento del click.

Al conseguir cambiarlos de orden, entonces eso hace que funcione el registro pero que no se pueda iniciar sesión. Entonces por consola se lee que "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') at script.js line 65" pero no encuentro el por qué al parecer no se está enviando nada al hacer click. Es como un callejón sin salida.

Incluso llegué pensar que no se colocó ninguna interfaz o mensaje para cuando el inicio de sesión sea exitoso, y esto incidía en parte del problema, pero creo que no lo es.

La idea es que el usuario se registre, y una vez realizado este proceso, pues inicie sesión.

```
class Cuenta {
  constructor(usuario, contrasenia) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
  }
}

registrarse = () => {
  let mensajeError = targetInputId("error");
  let inputUsuario = targetInputId("floatingInput");
  if (!validarUsuario(inputUsuario.value)) {
    let inputContrasenia = targetInputId("floatingPassword");
    let inputContrasenia2 = targetInputId("floatingPassword2");
    if (inputContrasenia.value == inputContrasenia2.value) {
      cuentas.push(new Cuenta(inputUsuario, inputContrasenia));
      window.location.href = "inicio-sesion.html";
    } else {
      mensajeError.innerText = "La contraseña no coincide.";
    }
  } else {
    mensajeError.innerText =
      "El nombre de usuario ya existe.\nIngrese un nombre de usuario no existente";
  }
};

iniciarSesion = () => {
  let mensajeError = targetInputId("error");
  let inputUsuario = targetInputId("floatingInput");
  if (validarUsuario(inputUsuario.value)) {
    let inputContrasenia = targetInputId("floatingPassword");
    if (validarContrasenia(inputUsuario.value, inputContrasenia.value)) {
      window.location.href = "index.html";
    } else {
      mensajeError.innerText = "Contaseña incorrecta.";
    }
  } else {
    mensajeError.innerText = "El nombre de usuario no existe.";
  }
};

targetInputId = (id) => {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

validarUsuario = (busqueda) => {
  return cuentas.some((elemento) => elemento.usuario == busqueda);
};

validarContrasenia = (usuario, contrasenia) => {
  for (const cuenta of cuentas) {
    if (cuenta.usuario == usuario && cuenta.contrasenia == contrasenia)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
};

const cuentas = [];
cuentas[0] = new Cuenta("jere25", "jkl92rt");
cuentas[1] = new Cuenta("aaa", "aaa");
cuentas[2] = new Cuenta("bbb", "bbb");

let boton

let registro = targetInputId("registro");
registro.onclick = () =>{
  registrarse();
}

let inicioSesion = targetInputId("inicioSesion");
inicioSesion.onclick = () =>{
    iniciarSesion();
}
```

código del archivo index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Pagina principal - E-Commerse</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-signin">
      <h1>Pagina principal</h1>
      <a href="inicio-sesion.html">Cerrar sesion</a>
    </div>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

código del archivo inicio-sesion.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Iniciar sesión - E-Commerse</title>
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <div class="form-signin">
      <form>
        <img
          class="mb-4"
          src="data:image/webp;base64,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"
          alt=""
          width="150"
          height="100"
        />
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">E-Commerse</h1>

        <div class="form-floating">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingInput"
            placeholder="Nombre de usuario"
          />
          <label for="floatingInput">Nombre de usuario</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingPassword"
            placeholder="Contraseña"
          />
          <label for="floatingPassword">Contraseña</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" /> Recordar este usuario
          </label>
        </div>
        <button
          class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary"
          id="inicioSesion"
          type="button"
        >
          Iniciar sesión
        </button>
        <div>
          <p class="mb-3">
            ¿No tienes una cuenta?
            <a href="registro.html">Regístrate</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <p id="error"></p>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2022</p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

código del archivo registro.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Registrarse - E-Commerse</title>
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <div class="form-signin">
      <form>
        <img
          class="mb-4"
          src="data:image/webp;base64,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"
          alt=""
          width="150"
          height="100"
        />
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">E-Commerse</h1>

        <div class="form-floating">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingInput"
            placeholder="Nombre de usuario"
          />
          <label for="floatingInput">Nombre de usuario</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingPassword"
            placeholder="Contraseña"
          />
          <label for="floatingPassword">Contraseña</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingPassword2"
            placeholder="Vuelva a ingresar su contaseña"
          />
          <label for="floatingPassword2">Vuelva a ingresar su contaseña</label>
        </div>
        <button
          class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary"
          id="registro"
          type="button"
        >
          Registrate
        </button>
        <div>
          <p class="mb-3">
            ¿Tienes una cuenta?
            <a href="inicio-sesion.html">Inicia sesion</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <p id="error"></p>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">
          Al registrarte, aceptas nuestras <strong>Condiciones</strong>, la
          <strong>Política de datos</strong> y
          <strong>la Política de cookies</strong>.
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buenas, estoy intentando con tu código lo que pasa es que no me está guardando las cuentas en el array y no puedo probar el inicio sesión, pero he resuelto el hecho de que no salga el error del **Uncaught TypeError..** ¿Te sirve?

Comment: Agradezco tu tiempo Isanchezco pero considero la respuesta de @Artes mucho mejor y más completa.

Comment: hola @OtroMasComoTu de hecho pensando un poco más sobre el tema y también podrias hacerlo obtenido el boton en general y después llamar la función dependiendo el `id`: `const boton = document.querySelector("button"); boton.addEventListener("click", () => { ( boton.id === "registro" ) ? registrarse() : iniciarSesion(); });`, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

me tome el tiempo de analizar tu código y entenderlo un poco, y salvo mi opinión no es un tema de **hoisting**, (tal vez esto no quepa en un comentario, lo había puesto ahí antes aclaro..) pero..; lo que pasa es que estas usando tu mismo **script** para dos archivos diferentes, por eso al momento de ir al **inicio-sesion.html**, el botón `id="registro"` se queda como `null` o hay un `type error` ya que no hay una referencia o id en ese archivo y viceversa, por eso el error. Por lo que recomiendo es: 1.- o generar un script para cada html, o en su defecto; 2.- tomar pathname de tu ruta y de ahí partir para ejecutar tu logica, por ejemplo puedes usar `clases` o `funciones`, por ejemplo:

```
// esto es de tu logica que muestras...
class Cuenta {
   constructor(usuario, contrasenia) {
      this.usuario = usuario;
      this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
   }
}
/*aca obtienes las ruta cuando cargas el dom*/
window.addEventListener("load", () => {

  //console.log("Pagina cargada");
  //obtienes el pathname
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  console.log( url.pathname );
  
  /* en base al path ejecutas tu codigo o escuchas los eventos del
   del click*/

  if( url.pathname === "/inicio-sesion.html" ) {
     new INICIO();
     inicio();
  
  else {
    new REGISTRO();
    registro();
  }
});
class INICIO {
constructor() {
    const inicio = document.getElementById("inicio");
    console.log( inicio );

    inicio.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        console.log("Click en inico");
    });
  }
}
class REGISTRO{
   constructor(){
    const registro = document.getElementById("registro");
    console.log( registro );
    registro.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        console.log('click en registro');
    });
  }
} 
 const inicio = ()=>{
   const inicio = document.getElementById("inicio");
   console.log( inicio );
 }
 const registro = ()=>{

    const registro = document.getElementById("registro");
    console.log( registro );
  }
```

Comente todo tu código detrás para saber los errores hacia la referencia, pero lo podrías desarrollar partiendo de aquí. Verás que ya no existe el error a la referencia o el `typeError`. Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

En caso que desees mantener el `script.js` para ambos procesos (de registro e inicio de sesión) puedes usar esto al final de tu código (reemplázalo):

```
 if(registro) {
    registro.addEventListener("onclick", function() {
        registrarse(); 
      });  
  } else if(inicioSesion) {
    document.querySelector("#inicioSesion").addEventListener("onclick", function() {
        iniciarSesion(); 
      });  
  }
```

Aunque lo recomendable sería usar dos `.js` para no confundir ni mezclar procesos de la lógica de negocio.